# How to use fold/reduce to achieve this in scala ?

Tags: scala, reduce, fold

I've a class

```
case class PlaceHolder(time: Long, a: Int, b: Int)
```

I've a list of `PlaceHolder` objects and I want to create one object which contains the sum of all the values of field `a` and `b`. I don't care about `time`. I believe it can be done with fold/reduce operations but cannot figure how to do it with two fields.

```
scala> val range = 1 to 10
range: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> val placeholders = for{ i <- range} yield PlaceHolder(i,i,i) 
placeholders: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[PlaceHolder] = Vector(PlaceHolder(1,1,1), PlaceHolder(2,2,2), PlaceHolder(3,3,3), PlaceHolder(4,4,4), PlaceHolder(5,5,5), PlaceHolder(6,6,6), PlaceHolder(7,7,7), PlaceHolder(8,8,8), PlaceHolder(9,9,9), PlaceHolder(10,10,10))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
placeholders.foldLeft(PlaceHolder(0,0,0))((acc, p) => PlaceHolder(acc.time + p.time, acc.a + p.a, acc.b + p.b))
```

or

```
placeholders.reduce((acc, p) => PlaceHolder(acc.time + p.time, acc.a + p.a, acc.b + p.b))
```

or you could add a `+` operator to `PlaceHolder`:

```
case class PlaceHolder(time: Long, a: Int, b: Int) {
    def +(other: PlaceHolder) = PlaceHolder(this.time + other.time, this.a + other.a, this.b + other.b)
}
```

then you can do:

```
placeholders.reduce(_ + _)
```